# CSS: Drop Line Menu Moving Down On Scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using CSS Drop Line Menu but the problem is whenever I scroll down, the line also move down.
I'm not sure which CSS is active for this function, so I can't provide CSS code but everything is on the site.
Here is my url:
https://www.thewillowhostel.com/

Comment: You don't want to fixed header after scroll down ?

Comment: So basically you want to show border bottom to the active menu link. Right ?

Comment: I want to fix position of  header but want I want is to remove the line under the menu that's malfunction when we scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fixed header after scroll down open your style.css file and go on line `234` then remove position:fixed; in the `.gdlr-fixed-header` class.

```
.gdlr-fixed-header {
    position: fixed; <--Remove This
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you solution: Update your css with below properties

```
.gdlr-navigation-gimmick {
   top: 22px !important;
}
body.header-style-2 .gdlr-navigation-wrapper {
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried it on my local serve that's fine.
Here is the solve. When your gdlr-fixed-header  menu active that time the line could not find the mother that's why line break the rule.

```
.gdlr-fixed-header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Thank you.